# Rails: Solr Sunspot in Production Returning 404 when Reindexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, production-environment, sunspot

When I run `RAILS_ENV=production rake sunspot:solr:reindex`, I receive the following error message:

```
rake aborted!
RSolr::Error::Http: RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found
```

...

```
URI: http://localhost:8080/solr/default/update?wt=ruby
Request Headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}
Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><delete><query>type:Piece</query></delete>"
```

I've used [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-solr-on-ubuntu-14-04) to set up Solr, also referencing [this page](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Configure-Solr-on-Ubuntu%2C-the-quickest-way) for specific Sunspot configuration. My config/environments/production.rb file includes: `Sunspot.config.solr.url = 'http://localhost:8080/solr'` and my config/sunspot.yml file looks like the following:

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8080 #tomcat defaults to port 8080
    path: '/solr'
    log_level: WARNING
    pid_dir: '/var/run'
    solr_home: solr

development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr/development
    solr_home: solr

test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/test
```

I've tried everything outlined in similar posts--killing all Solr processes, starting and stopping the Solr server, deleting the entire solr directory, adding to my config files, etc. None of them have worked. I can manually access [hostname]:8080/solr, but I simply cannot reindex or seed my db.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails app: Solr throwing RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found when executing search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19759906/rails-app-solr-throwing-rsolrerrorhttp-404-not-found-when-executing-searc)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue was that this Solr installation has a different schema.xml file than the schema.xml file that must be used for Sunspot. What I did was I copied the schema.xml file on my local machine and pasted it into the schema.xml in `/usr/share/solr/conf/schema.xml` on my production machine. I restarted the Solr instances and deleted the Solr file in the rails application. I also messed with the config files quite a bit. I removed the line in the `production.rb` file and my `sunspot.yml` file looks like:

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8080 #tomcat defaults to port 8080
    path: /solr
    log_level: WARNING
    solr_home: solr
```

Really a pain...I hope this gem will be better documented for production use in the future.